# Text not appearing when using Twitter intent to create custom tweet

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, encoding

## Problem

I'm trying to using twitter intent to tweet out a pre-written, custom tweet. But when I click `fa-twitter` the box appears blank. I think the problem may be how I'm encoding the URL?

### scripts.js

```
function shareTeam(){
    $(".fa-twitter").click(function(){

       // Create an empty array
       var teasers = [];

             // Grabs the names of all the players in the span
             // Sets a variable marking the indexOf each of the names
             // If the index doesn't find a space, it returns -1, which returns the full name
             // Otherwise it will return only what follows the space
             var lastNames = $("li span").map(function() {
                 var name = $(this).text();
                 var index = name.indexOf(" ");
                 return index == -1 ? name : name.substring(index + 1);
             }).get();
             // console.log(lastNames);

            // var regularNames = lastNames.slice(0, 3); // Same as below, but no shuffling
            var regularNames = lastNames;

            regularName1 = regularNames[0]; // Forward
            regularName2 = regularNames[1]; // Forward
            regularName3 = regularNames[2]; // Defenseman
            regularName4 = regularNames[3]; // Defenseman
            regularName5 = regularNames[4]; // Defenseman
            regularName6 = regularNames[5]; // Goalie

            // Find me a random number between 1 and 3
            // Where 1 is the start number and 3 is the number of possible results
            // This is zero-indexed? So the numbers will be one lower than the actual teaser #
            var teaser = "teaser";
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            console.log(rand);

            // Concatenate the two strings together
            teaseRand = teaser.concat(rand);

            // These are the components that make up that fullURL
            var baseURI = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?";
            var twitterUsername = "@stltoday";
            var interactiveURL = "http://staging.stltoday.com/STLblues";

            // Randomly generate one of three teasers
            var teaser1 = regularName3 + " to " + regularName2 + " back to " + regularName1 + " — GOAL! Create your own all-team #STLBlues team: ";
            var teaser2 = "My #STLBlues dream team has " + regularName3 + " and " + regularName4 + ". Build your own: ";
            var teaser3 = "My #STLBlues dream team has " + regularName4 + " and " + regularName5 + ". Build your own: ";
            var teaser4 = "My #STLBlues team will skate circles around yours! Pick your team: ";
            var teaser5 = regularName6 + " with the glove save! ";
            var teaser6 = "Pick your #STLBlues dream team from 50 of the best @StLouisBlues to hit the ice: ";

            // Push teasers into array
            teasers.push(teaser1);
            teasers.push(teaser2);
            teasers.push(teaser3);
            teasers.push(teaser4);
            teasers.push(teaser5);
            teasers.push(teaser6);

            // This is the full url that will be switched in and out
            var fullURL = "text="+teasers[rand]+"&url="+interactiveURL+"&via=("+twitterUsername+")";
            // var fullURL = interactiveURL+"&via="+twitterUsername+"&text="+teasers[rand];
            console.log(fullURL);

            // It needs to be encoded properly as well
            var encodedURL = baseURI+encodeURIComponent(fullURL);

            // Change the href to the link every time the Twitter button is clicked
            $(".link--twitter").attr("href", encodedURL);
            console.log(encodedURL);

            // if (lastNames.length === 6) {

            // } else {
            //     var encodedURLGeneric = baseURI+encodeURIComponent(fullURL);
            //     $(".link--twitter").attr("href", encodedURLGeneric);
            // }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to encode each part individually

```
function shareTeam(){
    $(".fa-twitter").click(function(){

       // Create an empty array
       var teasers = [];

             // Grabs the names of all the players in the span
             // Sets a variable marking the indexOf each of the names
             // If the index doesn't find a space, it returns -1, which returns the full name
             // Otherwise it will return only what follows the space
             var lastNames = $("li span").map(function() {
                 var name = $(this).text();
                 var index = name.indexOf(" ");
                 return index == -1 ? name : name.substring(index + 1);
             }).get();

            var regularNames = lastNames.slice(0, 4); // Same as below, but no shuffling

            regularName1 = regularNames[0]; // Forward
            regularName2 = regularNames[1]; // Forward
            regularName3 = regularNames[2]; // Defenseman
            regularName4 = regularNames[3]; // Defenseman

            // Find me a random number between 1 and 3
            // Where 1 is the start number and 3 is the number of possible results
            // This is zero-indexed? So the numbers will be one lower than the actual teaser #
            var teaser = "teaser";
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
            console.log(rand);

            // Concatenate the two strings together
            teaseRand = teaser.concat(rand);

            // These are the components that make up that fullURL
            var baseURI = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";
            var twitterUsername = "stltoday";
            var interactiveURL = "http://staging.stltoday.com/STLblues";

            // Randomly generate one of three teasers
            var teaser1 = regularName3 + " to " + regularName2 + " back to " + regularName1 + " — GOAL! Create your #STLBlues team:";
            var teaser2 = "My #STLBlues dream team has " + regularName3 + " and " + regularName4 + ". Build your own:";
            var teaser3 = regularName4 + " to " + regularName3 + " back to " + regularName2 + " — GOAL! Create your #STLBlues team:";
            var teaser4 = "Pick your #STLBlues dream team from 50 of the best @StLouisBlues to hit the ice:";

            // Push teasers into array
            teasers.push(teaser1);
            teasers.push(teaser2);
            teasers.push(teaser3);
            teasers.push(teaser4);

            // This is the full url that will be switched in and out
            // It needs to be encoded properly as well
            var fullURL = baseURI+encodeURIComponent(teasers[rand])+"&url="+encodeURIComponent(interactiveURL)+"&via="+encodeURIComponent(twitterUsername);
            var genericURL = baseURI+encodeURIComponent(teasers[3])+"&url="+encodeURIComponent(interactiveURL)+"&via="+encodeURIComponent(twitterUsername);
            console.log(fullURL);
            console.log(genericURL);

            // Change the href to the link every time the Twitter button is clicked
            $(".link--twitter").attr("href", fullURL);
            console.log(fullURL);

            if (lastNames.length === 6) {
                console.log("Yeah, yeah, yeah");
            } else {
                $(".link--twitter").attr("href", genericURL);
            }
        });
}
```